# How to send email with hyperlink

Tags: email, hyperlink

I have a requirement to get a hyperlink with accept or reject anchor in a mail.Now, I need to send Email with a hyperlink. I tried many times but failed to get the hyperlink. How to do it?

```
public void SendEmail(OEMaster oe, int actionType, string accept)
{
  try
      {
         string mailTo = string.Empty;
         string mailFrom = string.Empty;
         string mailCC = string.Empty;
         string mailSubject = string.Empty;

         string mailMessage = "Dear Concern,";
         mailMessage += "";
         mailMessage += "";

   switch (actionType)
   {
  case 1:
       #region Mail Body
       mailSubject = "Advance Expense Request.";
       mailTo = oe.Approver.Email; // this.GetEmailAddress(oe.ApproverID);
       mailMessage += string.Format("Request for Accept");
       mailMessage += "";
       mailMessage += "";
       mailMessage += "The Details are as follows:";
       mailMessage += "";
       mailMessage += "";
       mailMessage += "Employee: " + oe.Employee.Name;
       mailMessage += "";
       mailMessage += "";
       mailMessage += "Amount: " + oe.Amount;
       mailMessage += "";

      mailMessage += "<a href='http:www.google.com" +accept + "'></a>";
```

## endregion

break;

Answer (score 0):

Should the line

```
mailMessage += "<a href='http:www.google.com" +accept + "'></a>";
```

read

```
 mailMessage += "<a href='http://www.google.com/" +accept + "'></a>";
```

Comment: int id = Request.QueryString["id"];  mailMessage += "<b> Your message : <a href='http://www.google.com'?id=0> Accept</a></b>"; Is it right way to passing query string value?